# Python как очистить строку от тегов Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, теги

Использую фрэймворк **Kivy**. У него есть свои теги для текста. Например:

`[color=#ff0000]color text[/color]`, `[b]bold text[/b]`, и т.д.

Мне нужна функция, которая будет очищать строку от этих тегов. Например:

```
my_str = "[color=#00ff00]Some [/color][b]beautiful [/b][size=24][b]text[/b][/size]."

my_str = ClearTags(my_str)

print(my_str)
# Outputs: "Some beautiful text."
```

Comment: Эта разметка похожа на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

def ClearTags(value):
   return re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '', value)
```

Comment: Имя функции лучше поменять на стандартную, т.е. на `clear_tags`, т.к. в вашем случае так классы называются в питоне (или функции в c#). Плюс я бы добавил аннотацию типов: `def clear_tags(value: str) -> str`

Comment: Поискал на эту тему и тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900941/strip-bbcode-from-string есть пример, который ваш код неправильно выполнит: `text = '[code]a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][/code]'` строка `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` вполне себе правильная, но она тоже будет обрезана

Comment: Поэтому, я бы рекомендовал попробовать модуль bbcode и решение с ним выложить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901237/5909792 . Посмотрите :)